# Include js file with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

In a PhantomJS script, I am trying to load a local JavaScript file that defines an array:

```
var webPage = require('webpage'),
    page = webPage.create();

injected = page.injectJs('./codes.js');
if (injected) {
    console.log('injected codes.js');
    console.log(myCodes);
}
phantom.exit();
```

**codes.js**:

```
myCodes = new Array();
myCodes[0] = { "stuff": "here" };
// more like this
```

I'd expect the myCodes array to be available.
Yet I receive

> injected codes.js
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myCodes

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer. Had to import the file with phantom.injectJs, not page.injectJs.

```
filename = './codes.js';
injected = phantom.injectJs(filename);
if (injected) {
    console.log('injected codes.js');
    console.log('myCodes data:', myCodes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to export your array in required file, like: `exports.myCodes= { whateverinarray };` and then reach it in main file, like  `injected.myCodes`